# apt-get command not found in coreOS (cos)

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, coreos

I would like to **install** **tools** in my cluster VM to debug, like *dnsutils* or *mysql* to test connections.
My cluster VM use **container optimized OS** (cos).

Whenever I try

```
apt-get update
```

I got an error

```
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox), execute

```
/usr/bin/toolbox
```

It will download docker images and login inside once completed, as root user.
You will be able to execute commands like apt-get update / install and debug